# Error opening Maven POM file dependency hierarchy in Eclipse - "Project read error"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

When I open a POM file and click on the "Dependency Hierarchy" tab at the bottom, it gives me the error, "Project read error".  It works with other projects in the same workspace, just not with this one.  Any ideas?

[image]

**EDIT**

In response to @Yhn's answer.

1. Running the compile and package phases outside of Eclipse from the command-line work as expected.  It compiles the application and builds the final WAR file.
2. Eclipse is indeed pointing to the default location of the Maven settings.xml file, so it should be aware of the custom repositories that are defined in it (my company has its own Maven repository).
3. I can open and edit the POM file from Eclipse, so it must have read/write permissions to the file.
4. The project is not configured in Eclipse as a Maven project, so I cannot run the package phase from Eclipse (I can only run it from the command-line).

I wonder if it has anything to do with the fact that I was having trouble building the project with Maven 3 because apparently some of the transitive dependencies are configured for Maven 1, which [Maven 3 does not support](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-LegacystyleRepositories) (this is my theory anyway, based on some of the error messages).  I can build the project with Maven 2, but I still get messages such as the following:

```
Downloading: http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/dependencies/maven2/org/codehaus/xfie/bcprov-jdk14/133/bcprov-jdk14-133.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.codehaus.xfire:bcprov-jdk14:pom:133' in repsitory mule (http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/dependencies/maven2)
```

It must be able to find these dependences however, because it downloaded the JARs just fine and can build the application.  It seems like the problem is that the dependencies don't have POM files associated with them, which is maybe why they cannot be used with Maven 3.  This might also be why I cannot view the Dependency Hierarchy in Eclipse.

**EDIT 2**

I converted the project to a Maven project by going to "Configure > Convert to Maven Project".  When I open the POM file, I see the error:

`ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for woodstox:wst (Click for 140 more)`

(woodstox:wst is another transitive dependency of the project).  An error appears in the "Markers" view for seemingly every depedency and transitive dependency in my project.  However, I can successfully build the project by doing a "Run As > Maven build". (**Edit:** This might be because this project has no Java source code, but the JARs of the dependencies correctly appear in the final WAR.)  The Dependency Hierarchy still gives the same error--"Project read error".

About the "Unable to find resource" messages--but this only appears for a handful of transitive dependencies.  The project has many more transitive dependencies, but these messages do not appear for them.  It seems like, because the dependencies do not have POM files, that Maven tries to search for them every time the project is built.  Is this normal not to have POMs??

How might I go about getting a repo manager?  Is this something that would have to be installed on the company's Maven repository or can you install it on your own workstation?

Comment: If I recall correctly; eclipse has a maven console showing errors when things like this happen. Could you check if that console shows anything that could help identifying the cause of this?

Comment: Can this project correctly compiled packaged etc. via Console ?

Comment: @Yhn Do you know how I can open that console?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, I can run a `mvn compile`, `mvn package`, etc from the console without any trouble.

Comment: @Michael It should be in the normal console window; when clicking the 'Open console' button you should be able to select 'Maven console'

Comment: @Yhn Got it.  It just displays the same error (it prints it twice for some reason): `6/21/11 11:25:26 AM EDT: [ERROR] Project read error`

Comment: I had the same issue with one project and gave up on it. I'm just using mvn eclipse:eclipse now and using the project as a "normal" Eclipse project (no Maven dependency resolution). Seems like some discrepancy between Maven 2 an 3, since the Maven config page in Eclipse says that the embedded Maven 3 is always used for workspace resolution of dependencies. It's sad that one of the most used dependency management tools still can't work together perfectly with one of the most used IDEs... All my other project work fine, though. Just this one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this problem with some non-maven jars that I needed to include in my maven project. I put the jars in my local repository using this maven command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/test/gov.nist.xccdf-1.2.jar -DgroupId=gov.nist -DartifactId=xccdf -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.2
```

Then I referred to them as dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>gov.nist</groupId>
        <artifactId>xccdf</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This worked fine for a while, but I must have upgraded something in eclipse, and I started getting the error you describe.

**The fix is to take them out of the local repository, and redo the install-file asking maven to generate a pom for you:**

```
mvn -DgeneratePom=true install:install-file -Dfile=/test/gov.nist.xccdf-1.2.jar -DgroupId=gov.nist -DartifactId=xccdf -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.2
```

The command will cause a pom to be generated in the same directory (within your local repo) where the jar is placed.

In recent versions of eclipse maven support, the maven build is still done with maven 2 (if you right-click your pom.xml, choose run as mvn package for example).  The dependency analysis is now done with an embedded maven 3 plugin, which doesn't like a dependency that has no pom.xml.

Comment: Do you have a tip how I can find out which dependency causes this issue?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. If you made your project a maven project, you should run:

- Right Mouse Click on project | Maven | Update Dependencies or
- Right Mouse Click on project | Maven | Update Project Configuration

That worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Given the information through the comments:

mvn compile/mvn package work through console (I'm assuming outside of eclipse). Based on that, the POM file should be correct and dependencies can be resolved.

However; it could be that eclipse's settings aren't correct. For example, if eclipse has some own maven properties (instead of the default ~/.m2/settings.xml file); I can imagine it to fail resolving dependencies configured in the settings.xml used by maven itself. The settings for this should be in the Eclipse Preferences @ Maven > User Settings.

Also make sure that Eclipse can actually read the file (not locked, correct rights, etc).

Should this seem to be correct; can you try to run the mvn goal compile from eclipse? You can do this by right-clicking the project and selecting `run as > maven package`. That way it should run maven with the same settings as eclipse is using, and might show any additional errors in it's configuration.

--
In response to additional information:

Basically it tells you - when using Maven 2 - that it can't find a dependency resource (in this case bcprov-jdk14) in the given repository (codehaus/mule). When I search that maven module (bcprov-jdk14) I find it in the Maven central repo (through our local nexus) @ [repo1.maven.org/maven2](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk14/). Maybe that causes the error you're getting with Maven2?

And as the Maven 3 doc says; for Maven 1.x repo's; you should proxy them through a repo manager that can serve it to you as a maven 2 repository (I believe we do that here too for some repo's through Sonatype Nexus OSS)

ps.: Enabling maven dependency management in eclipse should be enough to be able to use maven run targets; if you would want to test it.

--

Sound like it can be multiple problems... given that the normal maven build works fine, one would think that maven can at least get the artifacts it depends upon and their dependencies... Yet, eclipse doesn't seem to be able to.

Double check if your Eclipse internet connection settings are correct? Since you were talking about a company repo, I'm assuming there will probably also be a proxy (I had to set up my Eclipse to use that one too; though for plugins (see next point)).

Another possibility, from experience, can be a rule-based proxy block on *.pom url requests (our proxy here blocks that to force usage of the local repo manager, how evil and annoying that is :(). You might want to try and open the .pom file it tries to download manually in your browser to see if this is the case (I can't, for example...).

To get the repo set up, you would probably have to ask the one responsible for the repository to add it as a maven2 proxy.

At the very least, it seems Eclipse is having issues getting the dependency poms (which are needed to build the dependency tree) from the internet. You could always try to ask some ICT crew (if they are capable enough...) about it at your company, maybe they have some useful hints.

Comment: @Yhn Thanks for your help.  Please see the edits to my question.

Comment: @Michael: see the edits in my answer, I hope they can help you some more.

Comment: @Michael Edited in some more.

Comment: @Yhn I just tried downloading a POM from the central repository and didn't have any problems.  I don't think there's a problem with Eclipse accessing the Internet--I can download plugins through "Help > Install New Software" just fine.

Comment: @Micheal: trying the [bcprov](http://dist.codehaus.org/mule/dependencies/maven2/org/codehaus/xfie/bcprov-jdk14/133/bcprov-jdk14-133.pom) pom from codehaus doesn't work here on my pc at home (I tried that one since that was the only link). Could you try if you can find the .pom files of one (or more) of those missing artifacts? Could be that a dependent project is having outdated dependencies on no longer existing repos?

Comment: @Yhn I think that's what the problem is--that these dependencies do not have POM files.  The version of the library that requires these dependencies is pretty old so that might be why it uses these wonky dependencies.  Here is another: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cwoodstox%7Cwstx-asl%7C3.0.1%7CN%2FA

Comment: @Micheal: Yeah, maven central even gives a "artifact not found" error. I think the best you can do is update those old dependencies to newer ones (where possible) and manually download/install the others in your local maven cache. For example, the bcprov is on maven central these days as org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.43

Comment: @Yhn Yeah, I'd love to update them, but I have to use this version of the library and changing any of its transitive dependencies could cause trouble.  Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

right click on the project, Maven->Update Project->Tick "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I added a new dependency to pom.xml without network connection. After this, I had so many problems such as "Missing artifacts", "Missing Descriptor", or "Project Read error". I solved this

1. delete the bad dependency just added from local repository.
2. rebuild local index.
3. re-add the dependency

Answer (score 1):

```
<properties>
    <!-- ********************** -->

    <!-- Plugin's properties -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>
```

this pom setting worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens if there is a typo in the pom that Maven cannot understand and then it throws `Project read error`. Like in my case I copied a maven dependency snippet and I by passed the version. Instead of typing the actual version # it was getting it dynamically `${asciidoctorj.version}` and my pom didn't have this in the properties section. So I got this error. Once I removed that and put a version number it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this after copying a local repository folder from another machine. The fix was to go into the repository folder I copied and delete
_remote.repositories along with the 'LastUpdated' files then refresh the Maven dependencies in Eclipse (Alt+F5)

Answer (score 0):

I faced same situation today. In my case it's caused by dependency name in wrong case. E.g.

Project A -> Project B -> Project C
In project B's pm file, I mistakenly specified the dependency artifacts name with "c" in stead of "C".

As in mac os, the files system is case insensitive. so I can build it in command line without detecting this mistake.

In Eclipse it breaks, but it provides very bad error message. In the error list, it says "dependency problem", but the name of dependency is empty. It also can't identify which line in the POM causes the problem.

When try to open "Effective POM" in POM viewer, it will show project read error. In the pop up error dialog box, it will show:

```
Could not read maven project
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
```

All the messages are useless and misleading.

I finally detected this problem by submit to Jenkins CI after wasted hours of time.

Answer (score 0):

I did maven clean install and the errors were gone

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue of "Project read error" while clicking on "Dependency Hierarchy" tab. In my project I had a parent pom and child pom.
Parent pom had a property `<appVersion>4.5<appVersion>` that was being used in child pom
`<version>${appVersion}<version>`.
I selected the main project, right click and choose run as maven clean. The console display showed warning that version is using expression but should be a constant. Replacing `${appVersion}` with constant value of **4.5** fixed the issue.